# Google Cloud Storage bucket has no project

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When I open the bucket directly by link [https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/[bucket_name]](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/%5Bbucket_name%5D) it doesn't show selected project, even though I can access bucket's content. I guess my account has full access to the bucket, but I can't figure out how to get project associated to it? I tried to go through all projects available to me, but none of them have Cloud Storage (I need to enable billing).

Comment: To list the buckets a project owns: `gcloud storage ls --project PROJECT_ID`. AFAIK, there is no command to get the project from a bucket name. You can infer the project number: `gcloud storage buckets describe gs://BUCKET_NAME` by reviewing the ACL list. That is typically accurate, but not always (the original owner might have been removed).

Comment: In addition to @JohnHanley's comment, you may also list your buckets using [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser). You may check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets) for reference. Please make sure to select the correct project ID. You can also check this link if [billing is enabled](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-billing-enabled). Hope these help.

Answer (score 1):

As per @JohnHanley:

> To list the buckets a project owns: `gcloud storage ls --project PROJECT_ID`. AFAIK, there is no command to get the project from a bucket name. You can infer the project number: `gcloud storage buckets describe gs://BUCKET_NAME` by reviewing the ACL list. That is typically accurate, but not always (the original owner might have been removed).

In addition, you may also list your buckets using [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser). You may check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets) for reference. Please make sure to select the correct project ID. You can also check this link if [billing is enabled](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/verify-billing-enabled).